# How to change css of class in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, css

let us assume that i want to change the color of text given to element through css class. i want to change color from white to red. Please give answer in pure javascript
my css code is like

```
.input {
background-color: black;
color:white;
}
```

Comment: `element.style.color = "red"`

Comment: You won't be able to change the class style definition.

Comment: @JeremyThille i want to change only code insie class not the whole className

Comment: @JeremyThille I don't think the OP want's to change the class name, but the definition of the class itself.

Comment: @Ifaruki this only changes the style on one element, not the style of a class.

Comment: @Ifaruki this will add inline style to element. i want to change inner css of class

Comment: @evolutionxbox Is there any way in jquery to change definition of class?

Comment: @AliRaza i suggest not to use jquery. the golden age of jquery is gone

Comment: @AliRaza you can add a new class definition, or override the old one, by adding a style element with CSS text content. AFAIK a CSS class definition cannot be changed by JS.

Comment: You could always dig into document.styleSheets and modify the css rules if that's what you want.

Comment: The duplicate is not correct. Why was it chosen?

Answer (score 2):

Unclear if you want to modify the css rule... but here is a way to manipulate the css using javascript

```js
for (let style of document.styleSheets) {
  for (let rule of style.rules) {
    if (rule.selectorText === '.input') {
      rule.style.color = 'blue'
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.input {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="input">hello world</p>
```

Comment: An easier way would have been to use [css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of all elements which use your class and modify their properties:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.color = "red";
}
```